# How to override Magento core block template?

Tags: php, magento, overriding

I'm currently developing a payment module, which is already working fine, even managed to override the success email template, however I can't seem to be able to put some simple additional info onto the checkout succes page.

I've been trying to find this  for hours but none of the solutions I've found are complete in describing where exactly to put which file. And what to write in the xmls.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why override a template when you can add your block via the layout system (which is how the normal content is added as well)?

Define a layout XML file for your module if you haven't already:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <your_module module="Your_Module">
                <file>your/module.xml</file>
            </your_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Use your layout file (app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/your/module.xml) to add a block to the  and  layout update handles. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <a_handle_for_you>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/text" name="yourblock">
                <action method="setText">
                    <arg>You should see this text.</arg>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </a_handle_for_you>
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <update handle="a_handle_for_you" />
    </checkout_onepage_success>
    <checkout_multishipping_success>
        <update handle="a_handle_for_you" />
    </checkout_multishipping_success>
</layout>
```

The above layout instructions should add content to the success pages for both the onepage and multishipping processes.

Comment: I guess the first xml goes to the config.xml, however what I would like to do is output some additional payment info from the Payment object, so I need a template to work with, which can of course be an additinal block

Comment: Yes. You will find a wealth of information on this additional topic at the [Magento Knowledge Base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates).